# Save Switch State using preferences, boolean not saving

Tags: android

I'm trying to save the state of my Switch. I have checked other answers on stackoverflow but still have not figured it out yet.

I have for my main activity a toggle button (tgbutton) and switch (simpleSwitch1). The preference for the toggle button works but the switch does not. Not sure if I am saving the preference correctly for the switch button but for most of the other forums/answer they have done as so.

Please advise,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Switch simpleSwitch1;
boolean switchState2 = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // initiate view's
    simpleSwitch1 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.simpleSwitch1);

    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("com.example.xyle", MODE_PRIVATE);
    simpleSwitch1.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("NameOfThingToSave",false));

    switchState2 = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", false);

    final ToggleButton tgbutton;
    tgbutton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggle);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    tgbutton.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("toggleButton", false));  //default is false

    tgbutton.setOnClickListener(new ToggleButton.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("toggleButton", tgbutton.isChecked());
            editor.commit();
        }
    });

    simpleSwitch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("com.example.xyz", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", true);
                editor.commit();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This is on " + switchState2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("com.example.xyz", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", false);
                editor.commit();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This is off " + switchState2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: Why don't you first check if onCheckedChanged is being called at all, next check if the boolean value is being saved, and finally check if the value is being restored properly.

Comment: Hey @Merlevede the onCheckedChanged works, It properly Toast if i change the state from true to false. With checking if the boolean value is being saved, I am also toasting the "switchState2" value which should be the stored preference for the switch state which stays at false which shows that it either isn't saving properly or if the switchState2 is not being initialized properly.

Comment: Your Toast is wrong, because it's always showing the original switchState2, not the preference. It should be:
`Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This is: " + sharedPrefs.getBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", false), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring new `SharedPreferences` each time you store/retrieve value which is unnecessary. Just use one `SharedPreferences` and trace different values with different keys. And you should store your values in `onStop()` cause that makes more sense. Try the below code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Switch simpleSwitch1;
boolean switchState2 = false;
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // initiate view's
    simpleSwitch1 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.simpleSwitch1);

    sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

    if(sharedPrefs.contains("NameOfThingToSave")){
       simpleSwitch1.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("NameOfThingToSave",false));
       switchState2 = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", false);
    }

    final ToggleButton tgbutton;
    tgbutton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggle);

    if(sharedPrefs.contains("toggleVutton")){
        tgbutton.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("toggleButton", false));  //default is false
    }

    tgbutton.setOnClickListener(new ToggleButton.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    simpleSwitch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        }
    });

}

     @Override
     public void onStop() {
          // Store toggle state
          sharedPrefs.edit().putBoolean("toggleButton", tgbutton.isChecked()).commit();

         // Store switch state
         if (simpleSwitch1.isChecked){
                sharedPrefs.edit().putBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", true).commit();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This is on " + switchState2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                sharedPrefs.edit().putBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", false).commit();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This is off " + switchState2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
       }
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. The problem is, you are using `different` preferences (`"com.example.xyle"` and `"com.example.xyz"`) to store and get `boolean` value.
2. The value of `switchState2` did not changed anywhere in your code, that's why on your `Toast` message its always showing same result.

**Try this:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Switch simpleSwitch1;
boolean switchState2 = false;

SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // initiate view's
    simpleSwitch1 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.simpleSwitch1);

    sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("com.example.xyz", MODE_PRIVATE);
    simpleSwitch1.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("NameOfThingToSave",false));

    switchState2 = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", false);

    final ToggleButton tgbutton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggle);
    tgbutton.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("toggleButton", false));  //default is false

    tgbutton.setOnClickListener(new ToggleButton.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("toggleButton", tgbutton.isChecked());
            editor.commit();
        }
    });

    simpleSwitch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", true);
                editor.commit();

                switchState2 = true;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This is on " + switchState2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("com.example.xyz", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", false);
                editor.commit();

                switchState2 = false;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This is off " + switchState2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

}
```